# Are there Costumes for the other Classes as well?

Tags: bravely-default

In the equipment shop, the merchants have, after restoring/upgrading something in Norende, a Costume Equipment which will give the person the appearance of the Freelancer Job no matter what Job they actually are.

I am wondering if it's possible for me to get something like that for the other jobs as I have already Mastered Black/White Mages, Knight, and Thief. I didn't see anything new in any of the stores and i like how Agnès looks as the Spirit Master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfotunately, no, there are no costumes for other classes. You will find that there are instead a unique costume for each character, and some extra costumes for specific characters, most notably Agnes and Edea.